# Строки в биты перечисления

Tags: c#

Есть перечисление

```
[Flags] enum SomeBits 
{
    Bit0 = 1, 
    Bit1 = 2,
    Bit2 = 4,
    Bit3 = 8
}
```

Как из строки "Bit0|Bit2" получить переменную со значением Bit0|Bit2? Я примерно представляю, что можно разбить строку на массив подстрок, в цикле foreach пройти по значениям и каждую сравнить с эталоном, используя switch. Но решение выглядит сложно. Как написать проще (если возможно)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для начала можно отказаться от сравнения с эталоном, использовав преобразование строки enum в значение при помощи System.Enum.Parse

```
SomeBits val = Enum.Parse(typeof(SomeBits), "Bit0");
```

Но от разбора на подстроки, думаю, никак не уйти.

Comment: SomeBits val = (SomeBits)Enum.Parse(typeof(SomeBits), "Bit0|Bit2".Replace('|', ',')); - получилось очень просто.